# How to set tax rate for not logged in customer in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

Is it possible to set tax rate for not logged in customer . In my store tax rate working fine for logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set tax for not logged in customer

To set tax for not logged in customer use below step

1. check not logged in customer's tax class from **customer -> Customer Group -> NOT LOGGED IN**

2.Then go to **Sales -> Tax -> Manage Tax Rules** you can create new rule or edit rule here

[image]

Here you need to select tax class for not logged in customer.

All done

Refresh the cache and tax will apply for not logged in customer.